# Why does this Webserver ignore my POST request and instead send me what I would get with a normal GET request?

Tags: c#, http, http-post, httprequest

I am trying to get specific data from a web server, which I only get after a POST request. On the Website, I fill in two fields in a form and submit. The result is shown as a text underneath the search area. [image]

I tried to send a request via a REST client application and via some c# code, but the Website never sends me back the result I want. It instead sends me the result I would get from a GET call without the data I want.

I think I'm missing some session data. I don't think I'm missing any POST Variables, because I looked at the request in the chrome network tab and compared it with my post request.

Or could it simply be the server, not allowing automated requests?

Comment: Check the session data using Telerik Fiddler or Wireshark.  You might also find a few other things you didn't see before.

Comment: Usually a header is missing or wrong.  Are all the header the same in chrome?  What about the Content_Type?